# Changing a markers location at set intervals

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I am trying to plot coordinates of a marker using a GeoJSON feature. I am able to plot my points fine but my issue is, when the interval happens the old marker stays on my leaflet map rather than removing the old marker or changing the coordinates of the original marker.

The code below is in my js file which has a set interval to read from a URL with my coordinates and this is where my marker is added to my map.

```
    window.setInterval(function nameSat()
    {
 $.getJSON('http://10.175.129.36/meo_coordinates_v2.json', function(data) {
         lat =`${data[1].Latitude  }`
         lon =`${data[1].Longitude }`

         //console.log("Lat: "+ lat + "Long: " + lon);

 geojsonFeature = {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "name": "Satellite",
        "marker-color": "#ff0080",
        "marker-size": "small",
         "popupContent": "<b>O3B M003</b><br>Longitude: "+ lat + " <br>Latitude: "+ lon
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [lon, lat]
    }
};

console.log("Lat: "+ lat + "Long: " + lon);


    var meo =L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature , {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
});
meo.addTo(mymap);


 })

    }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using a single instance of `L.Marker` (instead of building up a `L.GeoJSON`), you could simply use [`setLatLng`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#marker-setlatlng).

Since you're using a `L.GeoJSON` with a single GeoJSON feature, another approach is to use its [`clearLayers()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#layergroup-clearlayers) and [`addData()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#geojson-adddata) methods, e.g.:

```
// Create an empty L.GeoJSON and add it to the map
var meo = L.geoJson().addTo(map);

window.setInterval(function() {
   var geojsonFeature = {
     "type": "Feature",
      /* etc */
   };

   // Remove the current contents of the group
   meo.clearLayers();

   // Add the newly built GeoJSON features to the group
   meo.addData(geojsonFeature);
});
```

Please also be aware that using asynchronous functions (i.e. performing network requests) inside a `setInterval` callback may lead to race conditions (i.e. the responses to your network requests might be out of order, if one of them takes longer than the interval duration).

Answer (score 1):

Declare `meo` as a variable in the outer scope and then remove it if it is already in the map:

```
// outer scope
var meo;

var some_function() {
    // inner scope

    if (map.hasLayer(meo)) { // remove meo if it is in the map
        map.removeLayer(meo);
    }

    meo = L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature , { // assign new layer data to meo
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
    });

    map.addLayer(meo); // add meo to the map

}
```